# Function that changing global variables is out of work - how to fix it?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote a following code:

```
row = 16
col = 16

pl = -1
pr = 1
ql = -1
qr = 1

def Except(a, b):
    global pl, pr
    global ql, qr

    pl = -1
    pr = 1
    ql = -1
    qr = 1
    if(a == 0):
        pl = 0
    if(a == row-1):
        pr = 0
    if(b == 0):
        ql = 0
    if(b == col-1):
        qr == 0

    return None
```

The function `Expect(a,b)` checks the value of `a` and `b` and if `a` or `b` takes specific value it changes (global variable) `pl`, `pr`, `ql` and `qr`. But `qr` makes the trouble. 
I expect the code works as follows:

```
>>> Except(0,15)
>>> qr
0
```

However it doesn't work - `qr` doesn't changed. I don't know why the code doesn't work. (Another variables *does not* make the problem and works well.) Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple typo

change `qr == 0` to `qr = 0`

first checks if qr is equal to 0 and does no assignment, second is assignment operator